# Proxychains and urllib2 - Python

Tags: python, urllib2, tor

I wrote the following python script wich uses urllib2 :

```
    def http_response(url): 
       try:
          connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
          return connection.getcode()
          connection.close()
       except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
          return e.getcode()
```

It works well, but if I want to run it through tor, using Proxychains I get a `Connection Refused` error. My question is, is there a way to do the same things in a way that works also with proxychains, without making the Python script connect to the socks proxy itself?

Comment: Your code working without tor right ? If it's, there is some problem with your proxy configuration i guess.

Comment: proxychains works well with others programs

Comment: try this way; http://stackoverflow.com/a/9836661/1788956

Comment: yes, but i am asking if there is a way to make the script works with proxychains.